# How to include non-official programs' files into "Recent Files" list?

Tags: nautilus, files, 17.10, desktop-environments

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 (either Ubuntu or GNOME shell / desktop environment) and Foxit Reader as my default PDF reader. Whenever I modify an ODT and create a PDF file, I automatically open Foxit Reader to review it (it's in LibreOffice settings to open the PDF default program immediately after).

However, when I want to send the PDF file through my GMail account, I don't see my recent file in the "Recent Files" list.

So, my question is how to instruct GNOME or Ubuntu to include files opened with Foxit Reader in the aforementioned listing. Or is it a Nautilus settings?

Comment: Been a while since I coded for recent files type of stuff, but if I recall correctly it has to do more with how app is built, so i don't think it's  GNOME issue. I'd suggest filing a bug report to Foxit developers

Comment: @Sergiy-Kolodyazhnyy, where can I corroborate it is an app issue? Thank you, but I will wait if someone else shares more. However, I will ask Foxit developers, as you suggest.